# results query that handles AND, OR as well as "any values"

Tags: sql

I have a search page with a form where a user can set values for 2 different field (name and city). It works fine, but for both  fields, the user can choose "ANY" as an option for one when they only want results for that city. But if they choose ANY, they will get 0 results because my query is an AND query. I can't figure out how to construct this query so it shows results for both values or just for one value if they choose ANY for the second field.
I can't use "OR" because they might also want to have results for specific names in cities as well. 
What is the best query to allow for all options?

```
 <?
 //Connection

 $name = $_GET['name'];
 $city = $_GET['city'];


 $link = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass) or die('MySQL 
 error:'.mysql_error());
 mysqli_select_db($link, $dbname) or die('MySQL error:'.mysql_error());

 $query = "(SELECT * FROM people where name='$name' and city='$city')";

 $result = mysqli_query($link, $query);

 $num_rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);
 echo "$num_rows Rows\n";

 echo "<table border='1'>
 <tr>
 <th>School</th>
 <th>City</th>

 </tr>";

 /* fetch associative array */
 while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
 echo "<tr>";
 echo "<td>" . $row['name'] . "</td>";
 echo "<td>" . $row['city'] . "</td>";
 echo "</tr>";
 }

 /* free result set */
 mysqli_free_result($result);

 echo "</table>";

 mysqli_close($link);
 ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$query = "(SELECT * FROM people where (name='$name' or '$name' = 'ANY') and (city='$city' or '$city' = 'ANY')";
```

### Updated

Sorry, it's the quotes around the ANY.  Try this instead:

```
$query = "(SELECT * FROM people where (name='$name' or '$name' = \'ANY\') and (city='$city' or '$city' = \'ANY\')";
```

-or-

```
$query = "(SELECT * FROM people where (name='$name' or '$name' = \\\'ANY\\\') and (city='$city' or '$city' = \\\'ANY\\\')"
```

depending on whatever other escaping may be going on.

Also be aware of code injection, hopefully those user-entered strings were already escaped with something such as mysqli_real_escape_string().

I hope this helps.

Comment: won't cut it... ANY means all

Comment: Plus it just gives me at HTTP 500 error. So that's not the solution :(

Comment: @jaw This logic looks correct to me.  You might have another PHP problem at work here.

Comment: It worked fine in my code above. It only gave the 500 error when I tried the solution mentioned above.

Comment: @maSTAShuFu Do you have another approach? I can't even tell if the suggested one by jwolf works as it throws the 500 error, but it's not a php problem since my original code works, even though it doesn't solve my problem of handling "any" selections...

Comment: which sql database?

Comment: It is using mysql db and php

Comment: coding in mysqli

Comment: Thanks jwolf. Still getting 500 error with both of those :(

Comment: I was looking to solve the SQL question.  My PHP is too rusty to go much deeper on this - I'd just be guessing anyway since we don't know what else is happening to $query after this.

Comment: Well thanks anyway. To answer what else is happening, all I am doing is outputting the results like this:     echo "<td>" . $row['name'] . "</td>";   It is not a php question really as much as trying to get the sql logic right

Comment: The entire results page code is now shown in original question if it helps anyone...

Comment: @jwolf I made some adjustments to my code (updated in question) and tried your approach again. Getting these errors now: Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, string given 
Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, string given 

Warning: mysqli_free_result() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, string given

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following:

```
$query = "(SELECT * FROM people where name =  case  '$name' when 'ANY' then name else '$name' end and city= case '$city' when 'ANY' then city else '$city' end)";
```

Comment: This approach yields 0 results regardless of what is selected in both fields

Comment: I think all I need is a query where I can check if a variable was set IN THE QUERY and return all for that variable if it is not. Is this possible? Something like  where name='$name' and city=if(isset('$city')) else city =* ";    Does anyone know if this is possible and if so, what the php syntax might be?

Answer (score 0):

Please look at this demo and translate to php code

http://rextester.com/live/XSPV71393

```
SELECT
  *
FROM mytable
WHERE name_ LIKE (CASE
  WHEN @searchname = 'any' THEN '%%'
  ELSE concat('%', @searchname, '%')
END)
AND city LIKE (CASE
  WHEN @searchcity = 'any' THEN '%%'
  ELSE concat('%', @searchcity, '%')
END);
```

so php code should be something like below

```
$query = "SELECT  * FROM mytable WHERE name_ LIKE (CASE   WHEN ".$name." = 'any' THEN '%%'   ELSE concat('%', ".$name.", '%') END) AND city LIKE (CASE   WHEN ".$city." = 'any' THEN '%%'  ELSE concat('%',".$city"., '%') END);";
```

Comment: Thanks. But Union just lumps two select field results into one output list rather than comparing and also requires the similar data types for each field. Won't work when I add a zip codes field.

Comment: the purpose of the union is to include the keyword ANY so you can search with it... if you want zip codes to be seachable with any then you need to add it

Comment: i can try it. Not familiar with some of this syntax but looks off. Is this code meant for copy & paste as is just replacing mytable? Should name_ be changed to name?

Comment: @jaw this is funny. can you please check my answer again.. i've just added the right one for you haha.

Comment: Actually I caught something in my code that was off. Corrected it and tried your approach. Now I get these errors (and no results): Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, string given 
Rows 
Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, string given 

Warning: mysqli_free_result() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, string given

Comment: instead of using asterisk just explicit declare the column names

Comment: you also forgot to pass the query result  $result=mysqli_query($con,$query); and use $result to fetch assoc  https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_fetch_assoc.asp

Comment: Sadly my php syntax isn't great so your latest suggestion of what the php should look like is over my head until I read more tonight. I will keep plugging away. Thanks for your help...

Comment: check this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28671583/how-to-use-a-php-variable-in-mysqli?rq=1